# No Background Updates on iOS 9

Tags: ios, background, location, updates

I am implementing an App with continuous background updates on iOS 9. Even with allowsBackgroundUpdates set to YES, AlwaysUsage Description and with proper authorisation i am not getting location updates continuously. I am using Standard Location Services and Significant Location Services but not receiving any location updates when App is in Background. (App is in background/suspended but not terminated). Can anyone let me know if i have missed anything? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your iOS app must keep monitoring location even while it’s in the background, use the standard location service and specify the location value of the UIBackgroundModes key to continue running in the background and receiving location updates. (In this situation, you should also make sure the location manager’s pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property is set to YES to help conserve power.) Examples of apps that might need this type of location updating are fitness or turn-by-turn navigation apps